# Add a value label in Zii progress bar

Tags: jquery-ui, yii, progress-bar, yii-widgets

can I add a value label for a *Zii* progress bar?

```
$w =intval($model->fixed);
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiProgressBar', array(
         'value'=> $w ,      
         'htmlOptions'=>array(
                 'style'=>'width:200px;height:20px;',            
         ),
        ));
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Modify like this to put label to your progress bar

```
    $w =intval($model->fixed);
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiProgressBar', array(
     'id'=>'jui_progress_bar',
     'value'=> $w ,
     'htmlOptions'=>array(
             'style'=>'width:200px;height:20px;',            
          ),
     'options'=>array(
          'create'=>new CJavaScriptExpression('function(event, ui) {
                    $("jui_progress_bar").text("Your Text goes here");
                }'),
          )
      );
```